# Can I instantiate a new object of current class in the class definition

Tags: c++, class, oop

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
 public:
    A(int n = 1) : i(n) {}

    void Transform(int j)
    {
        // I want to create a new object and assign that object to "this"
        A *obj = new A(j);
        delete this;
        this = obj;
    }
private:
    int i;

};
```

Can I instantiate a new object of class `A` inside the function `Transform()` of class `A` and assign the new object to `this` while deleting the old object represented by `this`?

Comment: If you're using C++, [avoid using new and delete](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-newdelete) and please familiarize yourself with [smart pointers](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-owner).

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign to `this`, but you can still swap the object represented by `this` with a local object created in `A::Transform()`:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
 public:
    A(int n = 1) : i(n) {}

    void Transform(int j)
    {
        A obj(j); // create a new object A
        std::swap(*this, obj);
    }
private:
    int i;

};
```

Comment: @ネロク Thanks a lot! There actually is a copy constructor and =operator in the base class. That solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Because `this` is an rvalue pointer, which can't be assigned.

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this)

> The keyword `this` is a prvalue expression whose value is the address of the object

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid C++ code, yet I think there is a simple way to achieve what You want:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
 public:
    A(int n = 1) : i(n) {}

    void Transform(int j)
    {
        *this = A(j);
    }
private:
    int i;

};
```